# anonymous error in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Guys I am facing the below irrelevant error.

```
500 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
at Function.createFromHexString (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:214:11)
at ArticleProvider.findById (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/articleprovider-mongodb.js:61:89)
at ArticleProvider.getCollection (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/articleprovider-mongodb.js:39:10)
at Db.collection (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:478:44)
at ArticleProvider.getCollection (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/articleprovider-mongodb.js:37:11)
at ArticleProvider.findById (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/articleprovider-mongodb.js:58:10)
at /home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/trucy-mongodb-express-node.js-blog-37daddd/app.js:63:21
at callbacks (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
at param (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
at param (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:243:11)
```

While I am just calling the `/blog/search` method which looks like this

```
app.get('/blog/search', function(req, res) {

        res.render('blog_search.ejs', {
            title: 'Search Contact',
            });
                 });
```

My `blog_search.ejs` looks like this

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
   <form method="post" action="/blog/search">
     <input type="text" name="title">
     <input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Please help me out with this error.I get this error while accessing it with the URL as well as the a href.

Comment: FYI - an ObjectID is 12 bytes in MongoDB - is there anywhere you could be passing something odd into an ObjectID constructor or similar?

Comment: yeah Adam I got you.Actually i wrote the search module after the modules where there wer objectId passings.So i moved it above that and it worked.Thanks...!!!

Comment: If you put your own answer in with the details you can accept it, get credit - it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah actually search module was written under the ID fields so it was unable to perform anything.